# How to access MS word content by page number in Apache POI?

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi

Are there any functions in Apache POI that let you to access MS word content by page number?

Comment: No, because "the page" is not a main structuring element in word processing. A `Word` document body consists of a stream of body elements (paragraphs, tables, pictures, ...). On which page those elements will be is determined while rendering and is dependent of many different things (page settings, printer settings, ...). Only if the page breaks are explicitly set in document content (via page break flag in paragraph), then it will be possible to say, that this paragraph is top of a new page.

Comment: @AxelRichter OK, is it possible to access MS word content by page number via some kind of technology?

Comment: Any technology which is able rendering `Word` document page wise. So it must have it's own renderer. But there is no guarantee that this technology does rendering the document exactly the same as `Word`. So I would questioning the requirement "to access MS word content by page number". Why is it necessary? Is it really necessary?

Comment: @AxelRichter I have two ``Word`` files, one of which is the table of contents and the other is the real content, I want to split the real content according to the table of contents. Maybe this is a wrong idea. Are there other ways?

Comment: In TOC you have the headings together with the page numbers which are set from the last rendering and last updating the TOC. Splitting the document according to the headings will be the better approach. A heading in the document is a paragraph having the same text as in TOC and having a style named "heading..." set.

Comment: @AxelRichter OK, I will try this way. Thanks!