# XWPF delete first page

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I'm looking for removing first page of my world document using [XWPFDocument](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html).

```
XWPFDocument document = getTemplateFromFile('file.docx');
```

Actually in `document.getBodyElements()` I have 40 [XWPFParagraph](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html) and no one of them is telling me when page break is added.

What is the best way to achieve this? The best would be to remove page we want using `document.getPages().removePage(pPosition);` ^^

Comment: ["the page" is not a main structuring element in word processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465814/how-to-access-ms-word-content-by-page-number-in-apache-poi?rq=1)

Comment: thanks, then if i add manually break page in world how find position of his paragraph in bodyElements ?

Comment: A page break is set in a [CTR](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTR.java). One of the [CTBr](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTBr.java) in this `CTR` is of type [STBrType.PAGE](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/STBrType.java#STBrType.0PAGE).

Comment: i just realize i need add COVER page because all others pages have header+footer but cover page as first page is what i need instead. My question how word add cover page does it contains STBrType.PAGE too ? because my hacky code works when i add simple break page but not works with cover page which seems visualy in word contain pagebreak but my code not works if I add it, seems xml is different

Comment: "...COVER page...seems xml is different": Yes, it is. But no reason for guessing. Simply unzip the `*.docx` and have a look at `/word/document.xml` then you will see. And no, there is not any high level support for this in `XWPF` until now.

Comment: already did it my first bodyElements is instanceof XWPFSDT and when I try `document.removeBodyElement(0)` on debugging it is correctly deleted but my output file still continue contain cover page, while with page-break `document.removeBodyElement(0)` works correctly.